# How can I use Object Oriented Javascript to interact with HTML Objects

Tags: javascript, html, oop, object, design-patterns

I am very new to object orientated javascript, with experience writing gui's in python and java. I am trying to create html tables that I can place in locations throughout a webpage. Each html table would have two css layouts that control if it is selected or not. I can write all of the interaction if I only have one table. It gets confusing when I have multiple tables. I am wondering how to place these tables throughout a blank webpage and then access the tables individually. I think I am having trouble understanding how inheritance and hierarchy works in javascript/html.

NOTE: I am not asking how to make a table. I am trying to dynamically create multiple tables and place them throughout a webpage. Then access their css independently and change it (move them to different locations or change the way the look, independently of the other tables).

Comment: You might want to provide some explicit code examples of what you are doing or a link to a demo site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want to make changes in real-time and you're willing to use a library like jQuery, simply append the table(s) to the document and give each one a unique CSS id. Wherever your table generation code is taking place, just keep a counter and set the id to something like "mytable+counter_val".

From there you can reference each table and use jQuery methods to adjust the CSS to your liking.

A brief example:

```
var container_id = "#the_parent";

for (var i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
 var table_id = "mytable_" + i;
 var table_code = "<table id=" + table_id + "></table>";
 $(container_id).append(table_code);
}

// set border on table 7 (indexing at 0)
$("#mytable_6").css("border", "5px solid red");

// move table 5 (indexing at 0)
$("#mytable_4").css("top", "300px");

// animate table 2 (indexing at 0)
$("#mytable_1").animate({left : 300, top: 125}, 2000);
```

If you have the difference between selected and unselected separated into a single class, you can just add/remove that class:

```
// table 2 is now displayed as being selected
$("#mytable_1").addClass("selected");

// table 2 is now displayed as being unselected
$("#mytable_1").removeClass("selected");
```

See the jQuery docs for more information: http://docs.jquery.com/Main_Page

Comment: They all share a two CSS files. One for active and one for not active. On some action, I am going to select a table (change the between the two css files only for that table). Then drag it to a new location. I can do this with one table. I just don't know how to access the different tables when I dynamically generate them.

Comment: The easiest, fastest, and most efficient method for referencing HTML elements is via their assigned CSS id. Can you not set an id as I described above?

Comment: How would you suggest I keep track of these id's? The way I had this written I was trying to view each table as an object or node. Would I just place the css id as a field in that node?

Comment: If you're doing this in vanilla JS (ie. no jQuery library), then you'll likely be doing some document.createElement("table") calls. Just set the return of that to something you can store in your object. This will give you a reference to your table element inside whatever object you're creating to store your information. The return value essentially becomes your "this" reference to the table. This route doesn't require playing with CSS id's.

Comment: Ah, okay. If you append the elements via vanilla JS, you can convert the returned JS object to a jQuery object and store the jQuery object in your custom object. This avoids the need for CSS id's. If you append using jQuery's .append() you will need to either use an id to reference the new element, or traverse the DOM tree to get a handle for the new child you just inserted. The issue basically just boils down to retaining a handle to each table, so you can do that using id's or JS/jQuery objects.

Answer (score -2):

i don't understand the need of oop principles in your problem. why do you need inheritance and hierarchy for generating couple of elements and then alter some of their props?
if i understood corectly, you would want to keep track of each table you create so you can later change it's css props.
if you want to use js as an object oriented language, i would write a class definition for a table object :
`var Table = function(innerHTML,container){

    this.innerHTML = innerHTML;

    this.container = container;
}

//static member

Table.TABLES = [];//global reference to all the tables created

Table.prototype = {
    init : function(){

      this.dom = document.createElement('table');
      this.dom.innerHTML = this.innerHTML;
      this.container.append(this.dom);
      Table.TABLES.add(this);
    },
    setCssProp : function(name,value){
      this.dom.style.setProperty(name,value);
    }

}`
and then all you have to do is create a new table and initiate it :
`(new Table(table_content_here)).init();`,
and later on you can reference it by accesing the TABLES in Table class :
`for (var i in Table.TABLES)

   Table.TABLES[i].setCssProp(cssName,cssValue);`
i know that you know how to create tables, i was just suggesting that you keep a global reference to the ones you create to have acces to them later.